# No local costmap published after hydro migration

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-hydro, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear fellow ROS-Devs,

I have recently upgraded from Groovy to Hydro. My launch config, which uses the move_base package, worked fine under Groovy but fails under Hydro.

Under Groovy, move_base used to publish a correct local costmap as 'nav_msgs/GridCells' on the topics:

```
/move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space
```

Under Hydro, move_base now publishes the local maps as message type 'nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid' on the topic:

```
/move_base/local_costmap/costmap
```

(as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#Navigation_-_Costmap2D)). I have experimented with adding the 'plugins' parameter to the move_base config files, but I get the same result as without it ('Loading from pre-hydro parameter style').

In rviz, I can add a map and choose '/move_base/local_costmap/costmap' as topic, and all status indicators show green. However, no map is shown. If I do the same for '/move_base/global_costmap/costmap', I can see the global costmap that resembles the one served by mapserver.

When debugging on the command line, 'rostopic list' shows all topics as expected. But 'rostopic echo /move_base/local_costmap/costmap' only shows an empty map:

```
ros@Base:~$ rostopic echo /move_base/local_costmap/costmap
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1381741501
    nsecs: 967703624
  frame_id: map
info: 
  map_load_time: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  resolution: 0.0500000007451
  width: 119
  height: 119
  origin: 
    position: 
      x: -2.95
      y: -2.95
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0 ]
```

Note: Data abbreviated here, but there are only 0's in the data field.

Any ideas why I cannot see obstacles in the local costmap any more?

---

**Update 1**

As requested by David, here is the output of 'rosparam get /move_base/local_costmap':

```
ros@Base:~$ rosparam get  /move_base/local_costmap
footprint: '[[-0.4,-0.2],[0.4,-0.2],[0.4,0.2],[-0.4,0.2]]'
footprint_layer: {enabled: true}
footprint_padding: 0.01
global_frame: /odom_combined
height: 6
inflation_layer: {cost_scaling_factor: 10.0, enabled: true, inflation_radius: 0.5,
  robot_radius: 0.46}
laser_scan_sensor: {clearing: true, data_type: LaserScan, marking: true, sensor_frame: /base_laser,
  topic: /scan}
obstacle_layer: {enabled: true, max_obstacle_height: 2.0, obstacle_range: 2.5, raytrace_range: 3.0}
obstacle_layer_footprint: {enabled: true}
obstacles: {observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor}
origin_x: 0.0
origin_y: 0.0
plugins:
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
- {name: footprint_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::FootprintLayer'}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
publish_frequency: 2.0
publish_voxel_map: false
resolution: 0.05
robot_base_frame: /base_frame
robot_radius: 0.46
rolling_window: true
static_map: false
transform_tolerance: 1.0
update_frequency: 5.0
width: 6
```

Note: This is without specifing any plugins for costmap_2d layers, hence using pre-hydro parameter style.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90501/no-local-costmap-published-after-hydro-migration/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-14**:
Can you please post the output of rosparam get /move_base/local_costmap

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-10-15**:
@David: Please see my updated post above

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-15**:
Two possibly dumb questions: 1) Are you using RViz from Hydro? 2) Do you have obstacles from your laser within 2.5 m of your robot?

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-10-15**:
Here are my answers:

1. Yes, I used RViz from Hydro
2. There are plenty obstacles <2.5m around the robot, I can see them as dots in the RViz laser scan visualization

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-15**:
If you rostopic echo /move_base/local_costmap/costmap_updates, are there any non-zero values? I'm trying to tell if your costmap isn't being updated properly, or something is wrong with the visualization side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After more debugging I found out why move_base stoped publishing costmaps: During the migration to Hydro I tried to configure plugins for layered costmaps myself. Because I was having trouble with the name space of the laser scan sensor, I added the "obstales" namespace specifier in the "common_costmap_params.yaml" file:

```
obstacles:
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
```

When I later removed the "plugins" from the local and global costmap configuration (going back to pre-hydro compatibility mode) I forgot to remove the "obstacles:" namespace specification. D'oh!

---

Originally posted by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) with karma: 399 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-16**:
Ah, that's annoying. My apologies for not reading the parameters more carefully.